# Can I return a collection of multiple Derived Types from Dapper query

Tags: c#, inheritance, subclass, dapper

I have a class structure similar to this:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    //Additional Properties
}

public class DeviceA : Device
{
    //Specific Behaviour
}

public class DeviceB : Device
{
    //Specific Behaviour
}
```

I need to retrieve a list of Devices, or a single Device which is instantiated as the appropriate derived type (based upon a Type value in the Device Record in the DB). That is, the collection of `Device` objects should contain a number of objects with different Types, all of which are derived from `Device`.

I have implemented this the following way, but something just doesn't feel right about it.

```
public static IEnumerable<Device> AllDevices()
{
    using (var connection = CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection.Query<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM Device").Select<dynamic, Device>(d =>
            {
                Device device = null;
                if (d.DeviceTypeID == 1)
                    device = new DeviceA();
                else if (d.DeviceTypeID == 2)
                    device = new DeviceB();
                else throw new Exception("Unknown Device");
                device.DeviceId = d.DeviceID;
                return device;
            });
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this using Dapper, or is there a better approach?

Comment: It could be made more readable if you split the query into 2 separate queries.  One of DeviceType 1 and one for deviceType 2, then combined the two result sets for your return, but other than that, this seems to be a good solution.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for - particularly for the use case when retrieving a single device, as we don't know the device type ahead of time. (e.g. Get device by serial number, or some other identifier). Thanks, though, David.

Comment: If you're interested in tracking progress on this feature: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/262

Comment: I had the same issue for `BankAccount` type. In my database, I had the `BankAccounts` table with a discriminator property, and in my program, it was `CheckingAccount`, `SavingAccount`, etc. I am looking forward to `Dapper` to support it soon. Good solution for now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current build that is probably the only option (especially since the base-type is abstract). However, it wouldn't be unreasonable to think of ways of suggesting  a discriminated inheritance system. It isn't something we've done so far simply because it hasn't come up - but it doesn't sound impossible. The biggest problem I can see (other than IL-wrangling, obviously) is simply how we express the relationship.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. What would the difference be if the base-type was not abstract?

Comment: @GaryJL I didn't really mention abstract; at the moment it will just create the declared type (presumably the base-type); if there was something more "clever" going on, I would expect abstract base-types to work, as long as it never needs to create that type, obviously#

Comment: I'm surprised that this hasn't come up before. Seems to me that inheritance such as this is fairly common in many databases.

Answer (score -1):

I've came up with this solution:

```
using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            return db.Query<dynamic, DeviceA, DeviceB, Device>(@"
                Select
                    Discriminator,
                    ...
                From Device", (d, da, db) =>
                {
                    if (p.Discriminator == "DeviceA")
                    {
                        return new DeviceA();
                    }
                    else if (p.Discriminator == "DeviceB")
                    {
                         return new DeviceB();
                    }
                    return d;
                });
```

Sounds tricky, but it does work!

Hope it can help you.
            }

Comment: Does this code work? Where is "p" coming from?